# Imagemagick set interline spacing?

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

In application using imagemagick the design is specified like this:

```
   $draw->setFillColor(new ImagickPixel("#FFFFFF"));
   $draw->setstrokecolor(new ImagickPixel("#000000"));
   $draw->setstrokewidth(1);
   $draw->setFontSize(18);
   $draw->setfontweight(100);
   $draw->setFont("fonts/Impact.ttf");
```

I'd like to set interline Spacing in a similair fashion, but all samples are displayed like this:

```
  convert -density 72 -pointsize 12 -interline-spacing 12  -font Arial \
```

How can I access the `interline-spacing` command line parameter in PHP?

Comment: ahh, so you want a *PHP* command. I misunderstood. Deleting my answer

Comment: I see that's what I want!

Answer (score 3):

According to [this bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=60434), interline-spacing was added to PHP, but the method `ImagickDraw::setTextInterlineSpacing` isn't in my version of PHP:

```
# php -v
PHP 5.3.3-7+squeeze14 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Aug  6 2012 20:08:59)
```

You could see if it's in another version.  There's also a patch in the bug report that you could apply to your version of PHP.  Otherwise, you could write your own spacing method using the y-coordinate and multiple calls to `Imagick::annotateImage`.  Something like:

```php
<?php

$image = new Imagick();
$image->newImage(250, 300, "none");
$draw = new ImagickDraw();
$draw->setFillColor("black");
$draw->setFontSize(18);
$text = "Image Magick\nwowowow\nit's magical";
annotate_spaced($image, $draw, 0, 40, 0, $text, 40);
$image->setImageFormat("png");
header("Content-type: image/png");
echo $image;

function annotate_spaced($image, $draw, $x, $y, $ang, $text, $spacing)
{
   $lines = explode("\n", $text);
   foreach ($lines as $line)
   {
      $image->annotateImage($draw, $x, $y, $ang, $line);
      $y += $spacing;
   }
}
```

Makes:

[image]