# Downgrade ImageMagick version 7 to version 6 on Debian

Tags: debian, imagemagick

I installed the latest version 7 of ImageMagick on a Debian system, then discovered that it doesn't support some PHP Imagick function calls I need to use, such as setTextInterlineSpacing() and roundCorners(). How can I downgrade ImageMagick to version 6 on this Debian system?

Comment: Did you install it with apt-get? http://askubuntu.com/questions/138284/how-to-downgrade-a-package-via-apt-get

Comment: Yes, but the apt-get repositories don't seem to have version 6 available.

Comment: You can download a .deb package of the version you want. Then remove the version of the repository with `apt-get remove imagemagick` and install the .deb with `dpkg -i package-name.deb`.
But then you'll miss all (security-)updates and I recommend you to rather adapt your code... http://stackoverflow.com/a/14208363/2346308

Comment: Thanks - I decided to do what you suggest and adapt the code as much as possible.